# How to access y_true values in custom cost function?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, data-science

I want to write a custom cost function in which I want to acess the values of y_true and y_pred.
Like in this example they directly use y_pred - y_true but I want to access these elements for some other manipulation.

```
def custom_loss(layer):
    def loss(y_true,y_pred):
        return K.mean(K.square(y_pred - y_true) + K.square(layer), axis=-1)
    return loss
```

So how can I use these elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use them just like you would manipulate a numpy array, although this time `y_true` and `y_pred` are Tensors, not numpy arrays.

Look at this example:

```
def triplet_loss(y_true, y_pred, cosine=True, alpha=0.2, embedding_size=128):
    ind = int(embedding_size * 2)
    print('Shape of y pred is:', y_pred.shape)
    a_pred = y_pred[:, :embedding_size]
    p_pred = y_pred[:, embedding_size:ind]
    n_pred = y_pred[:, ind:]

    if cosine:
        positive_distance = 1 - K.sum((a_pred * p_pred), axis=-1)
        negative_distance = 1 - K.sum((a_pred * n_pred), axis=-1)
    else:
        positive_distance = K.sqrt(K.sum(K.square(a_pred - p_pred), axis=-1))
        negative_distance = K.sqrt(K.sum(K.square(a_pred - n_pred), axis=-1))
    loss = K.maximum(0.0, positive_distance - negative_distance + alpha)
    return loss
```

This is actually a loss function for a specific problem in Siamese Networks; but the gist is that `y_pred` is manipulated by means of slicing.

Therefore, you can slice/select some parts of `y_true` and `y_pred` according to your needs.

Comment: actually my problem is y_true and y_pred is multilabel and I need to find that while calculating loss function in t iteration what are the classes it predicts so I need to fetch those and need to find there embeddings as well. So when I am doing np.where(y_true) it is giving me an error, which is ok because it is an tensor and we are using this is an array. So what can we do then.

Comment: I have a dictionary {"Class_labels" : "embeddings"} , in loss function I need to find y_pred classes on every iteration and need to fetch respective embeddings as well then need to subtract those embeddings with the embeddings of the actual class, So it can reduce the difference between them.